# Exchanging lim and inf when rewriting $\inf\{t>0:\forall ε>0,S_t\cap B(x_0,ε)\subset S\cap B(x_0,ε)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can I prove that
$$\inf\{t>0: \forall ε>0, S_t \cap B(x_0,ε) \subset S\cap B(x_0,ε)\} \\= \lim_{ε \to 0}\inf\{t>0: S_t \cap B(x_0,ε)  \subset S \cap B(x_0,ε) \},$$
where $S$, $S_t\ (t \ge 0)$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I'm confused : isn't the left hand side a real number whereas the right hand side is a set? If not so: what's the liminf of a set?

Comment: @VanillaThunder.  It is not that liminf thing.  It is the limit of a function that maps a set determined by $\epsilon$ to the infinum of the set.

Comment: *where* $S$, $S_t$, $t\ge0$, *are closed sets* --- I'm guessing you mean something more like the following: "where $S$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ and, for each real number $t$ such that $t \geq 0,$ $S_t$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R.$" Also, why do you need this equality? In my case, at least, I'm more inclined to look carefully at something like this when some context is given, and I'm probably not alone in having such a preference. Finally, the tags "calculus", "general-topology", "functional-analysis" are not really appropriate, although after some context is added they might be.

Answer (score 1):

The question assumes that the assertion is true, which it is not. Let me give a one-dimensional counterexample. Let $x_0=0$, $S=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$, $S_t = \mathbb{R}$. Then:
$$\inf\{t>0: \forall ε>0, [-ε,ε] \subset S \cap [-ε,ε]\} = \infty,$$
since the condition is not true for $ε>1$. However,
$$\lim_{ε \to 0}\inf\{t>0: [-ε,ε]  \subset S \cap [-ε,ε] \} = 0.$$
If you dislike the convention that $\inf \emptyset = \infty$, you can take $S_1 = S$ (while keeping the other $S_t$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$) to get $1$ instead of $\infty$ for the first expression.